# reset! on reagent atom doesn't work as intended

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

So what I'm trying to do is a basic tabbed view using re-com's horizontal-tabs element. I added a v-box element and below that i want to have my tabs element and the body that corresponds to the tab. although on the :on-change i call reset! on the model of the horizontal-tabs and it doesn't seem to work.

```
(defn left-panel []
  [re-com/box
   :size "auto"
   :child (let [selected-tab-id (r/atom (:id (first left-panel-tabs-definition)))
                change-tab #(reset! selected-tab-id %)]
            [re-com/v-box
             :children [[re-com/horizontal-tabs
                         :model selected-tab-id
                         :tabs left-panel-tabs-definition
                         :on-change change-tab]
                        [(left-panel-tabs @selected-tab-id)]
                        ]])])

(defn forms-view []
  [:div "Forms View"])

(defn swagger-view []
  [:div "Swagger View"])

(def left-panel-tabs
  {::swagger #'swagger-view
   ::forms #'forms-view})

(def left-panel-tabs-definition
  [{:id ::forms
    :label "Forms"
    :say-this "Forms View"}
   {:id ::swagger
    :label "Swagger"
    :say-this "Swagger View"}])
```

If instead of

```
[(left-panel-tabs @selected-tab-id)]
```

i do something like

```
(do (log @selected-tab-id) [(left-panel-tabs @selected-tab-id)])
```

it'll always print the value that i've set my reagent atom at the beginning (in this case ::forms)

Comment: `@selected-tab-id` is running before your `change-tab` is called. Or in other words, you're setting it before `reset!` is called. If you want that to change, you'll probably need to set it in the change listener (although I've never used reagent before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to u/Galrog over at reddit I realised that in order for this to work i need to create a Form-2 component (3 forms of creating a component http://reagent-project.github.io/docs/master/CreatingReagentComponents.html#the-three-ways)

Changing my left-panel component to a Form-2 component re-renders both children on the atom's change

Code:

```
(defn left-panel []
  (let [selected-tab-id (r/atom (:id (first left-panel-tabs-definition)))
        change-tab #(reset! selected-tab-id %)]
    (fn []
      [re-com/box
       :size "auto"
       :child [re-com/v-box
               :children [[re-com/horizontal-tabs
                           :model selected-tab-id
                           :tabs left-panel-tabs-definition
                           :on-change change-tab]
                          [(left-panel-tabs u/selected-tab-id)]]]])))
```